# "Epochs" instead of "Steps" in the horizontal axis in tensorboard when using model_to_estimator?

Tags: tensorflow, logging, tensorflow-estimator, tf.keras

I am using [keras_model_to_estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/keras_model_to_estimator) to train an estimator and use tensorboard for analysis. The estimator logs the steps and not epochs, and hence the same appears in the x-axis in tensorboard.

I trained 10 epochs, but I get,

[image]

How do I make tf.estimator log epochs, so I can use that in x-axis?